# Dependencies with conflicting header versions of the same library

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, dependencies

I compiled a simple program that uses the tensorflow C api, so I link it against the `c_api.h` headers and the `libtensorflow.so`. It compiles and links to `program` just fine.

When I check the library dependencies of the executable with `ldd program` I get the direct dependencies and their locations:

```sh
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc5bf4e000)

libtensorflow_framework.so.1 => /home/myuser/libtensorflow/lib/libtensorflow_framework.so.1 (0x00007fd35d341000)

libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fd35f34a000)

(...other libraries...)
```

However, when I run the program I get the same error described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41964212/conflict-protobuf-version-when-using-opencv-and-tensorflow-c?rq=1):

```sh
[libprotobuf FATAL external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:78] 
This program was compiled against version 2.6.1 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, which is not compatible with the installed version (3.1.0). 
Contact the program author for an update. 
If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.
```

`libprotobuf` is NOT on the list of direct dependencies of the executable, so I assume it is a **sub dependency** *(i.e., a dependency of one of the libraries linked)*.

My understanding is that the library `dependency-that-uses-protobuf.so` was compiled using the `libprotobuf.so.2.6.1` file, while my compiler used headers of this same library but version 3.1.0. **Is that correct?**

If so, how could I tell the linker to compile using headers of that specific library version, and not other version *(using CMAKE)*, hence preventing runtime errors and getting linker errors instead. (?)

*My confusion is because so far I've only specified link libraries which are direct dependencies of an executable, so I don't know how to (and IF I should) link libraries that are sub-dependencies.*

Comment: "If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your **headers** are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library." - You need to tell the compiler to use proper include directory. Note, that it is possible that `libtensorflow_framework.so.1` library which you use is built incorrectly by itself.

Comment: Yes, but I mean specify in the CMAKE something like `find_package(LIB_PROTO protobuf PACKAGE_VERSION 2.6)` and then (somehow) include the package header folder of the found library. Otherwise it's not gonna be system agnostic, and I'd have to find the header folder myself, which is not very productive.
Also, the library is made available by tensorflow...

Comment: If you use [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/find_package.html), then it supports `version` argument. Just try to use it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev It turns out there is no point in telling the linker to link to some protobuf version, because my program itself doesn't depend on the library. Instead, `libopencv_core.so` and `libtensorflow.so` were statically linked to different versions of `libprotobuf.so`, and CMAKE has to find the headers of the library to compile, but it will give errors regardless, since the headers found will conflict _(see my answer bellow)._ The only workaround is to use versions of opencv and tensorflow compiled using the same `libprotobuf.so` version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround was to specify a different OpenCV path that has a compatible protobuf version:

```
# Finds installed opencv with incompatible Protobuff
# find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED ) 

# Finds the opencv with compatible Protobuf in my system
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED PATHS /usr/local NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
```

**Explanation**

Both opencv libraries and tensorflow library were compiled with a **static linking** to `libprotobuf`, [hence they don't show up with `ldd` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24492288/2076973). But the headers are still needed when compiling, and both have conflicting header versions.